# Sum a second coloumn in a query SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Difficult one to search for as its quite specific, I currently have teh dataset seen below when using my query, the issue is that under the net column this should be each net value added together for the products (Data sets will show what I mean), but I am unable to achieve this, when working I would also like to add a thrid column to this and sum the values there too, so its important to get this right.

Current Query:

```
SELECT
    product, Net,
    COUNT(OrderNumber) AS CountOf
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    STATUS = 'booking' AND
    Date(OrderDate) <= CURDATE() AND 
    Date(OrderDate) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)
GROUP BY
    product
```

Dataset:

```
id | product | status  | Net
-----------------------------
1  | pd1     |quote    | 10
2  | pd2     |booking  | 15
3  | pd4     |booking  | 20
4  | pd2     |cancelled| 15
5  | pd2     |booking  | 15
6  | pd1     |booking  | 10
7  | pd1     |booking  | 10
```

Current Result set:

```
product | Sales  | Net
------------------------
pd1     |3        | 10
pd2     |3        | 15
pd4     |1        | 20
```

Desired Result Set:

```
product | Sales  | Net
------------------------
pd1     |3        | 30
pd2     |3        | 45
pd4     |1        | 20
```

I think that should make sense

Comment: Forgot to add it, changed

Comment: use sum(Net) instead of net in the select part of ur query

Comment: just do a sum(net) instead of just net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sum for Net column. This is yours solution:

```
SELECT
    product, sum(Net) as Net,
    COUNT(OrderNumber) AS CountOf
FROM
    sw_orders
WHERE
    STATUS = 'booking' AND
    Date(OrderDate) <= CURDATE() AND 
    Date(OrderDate) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)
GROUP BY
    product
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    product, SUM(Net) AS Net,
    COUNT(OrderNumber) AS CountOf
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    STATUS = 'booking' AND
    Date(OrderDate) <= CURDATE() AND 
    Date(OrderDate) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)
GROUP BY
    product
```